# How to get control.Handle property across threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to parallel programming and while trying to plot the measurement results I got into the infamous error "Control control name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." .

After many hours of Web browsing and failed experiments I have to give up and seek for advice.

What I am trying to do is to do some plotting in a separate thread while the program continues its execution.

In the plotting routine (on a Panel control) I use quite extensively the API calls (Polyline, BitBlt, etc...) where I have to use the IntPtr hDCh_Dst = Win32.GetDC(pnlSchermo.Handle).

I found on the Web thousands of suggested solutions to this problem (almost all for setting properties and a few for getting) but I am not able to make them working.

Here is the (simplified) code that I am currently testing in a WFA project.

```
do
{
    // Data acquisition and processing...
    // etc...

    // Plot the measurement results...
    Thread thrDisegna = new Thread(() => DisegnaGrafico(NcF: NcZxF));
    thrDisegna.Start();

    // Do some other processing...

    // Wait for the end of the plot job:
    while (thrDisegna.IsAlive);

}
while (bMisuraOn);

private void DisegnaGrafico(string HcTipo = "", int NcF = 0)
{
    // Some initialisations...

    // Call the method XY in the Class QL (that is an instance of the Class Quadro) for scaling the pnlSchermo control and do some API plot:
    QL.XY(pnlSchermo, ..., ..., ref hdcDst, ..., ...);

    // Some other API plotting using the hdcDst...
}

public void XY(Panel pnlSchermo, ..., ..., ref IntPtr hdcDst, ..., ...))
{
    // ...

    // Here is where I need to use the pnlSchermo.Handle:
    hDCh_Dst = Win32.GetDC(pnlSchermo.Handle); // <-- Fails with the "Control control name accessed ..." exception.

    // or... but doesn't work either and the program hangs:
    pnlSchermo.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { hDCh_Dst = Win32.GetDC(pnlSchermo.Handle); }));

    // or... the program doesn't hangs, no exception thrown but returns _hDCh_Dst = 0. Does it need a EndInvoke?
        IntPtr _hDCh_Dst = IntPtr.Zero;
    pnlSchermo.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        _hDCh_Dst = pnlSchermo.Handle;
    }));
        hDCh_Dst = Win32.GetDC(_hDCh_Dst);

    // or... other solutions found on the Web and tested without success...
}
```

Ciao and thanks for the attention.

Franco

Comment: The sane thing to do when an exception tells you that you are doing it wrong is to stop doing it wrong.  You can "plot" to a bitmap in a worker thread. When you're done then you can it displayed in a window.

Comment: This is exactly what I do: I plot the scaled reticule on a BitMap, then I add on it the measurement curve (Polyline) but, at the end, I have to BitBlt it to the Panel control and here is where I need to have the control.Handle handy. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

More and more hours of Web browsing gave their fruits!

The problem, with the Control.Invoke hanging the application, was due to the cross interference of Invoke, that waits its completion before returning, and the main Thread looping in the:

while(thrDisegna.IsAlive);

It was enough to replace this line with:

do { Application.DoEvents(); } while (thrDisegna.IsAlive);

to have the following Handle access method working:

```
        IntPtr hDCh_Dst1 = IntPtr.Zero;
        pnlSchermo.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { hDCh_Dst1 = Win32.GetDC(pnlSchermo.Handle); }));
        hDCh_Dst = hDCh_Dst1;
```

Now, just for sake of curiosity, I have to investigate why the pnlSchermo.BeginInvoke(...) continues to return zero...

Ciao and to the next.

Franco